# Closing a question because the question is not really on SO?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282124/recursive-database-driven-navigation-in-coldfusion) the user asked for help about a question and code he posted somewhere else. Of course it got downvoted and the first comment explained why:

> If your link breaks the question here
>   is pretty much worthless... can't you
>   bring the question here?

... but he did get an answer (not sure if the answer is valid, I don't know the technology).

What should be done here? Close the question (new closing reason) ? Edit the question to retrieve all the information?

Comment: Just a heads up, that question will probably be deleted as soon as it's eligible, breaking your link.  I'd delete it right now, but I don't want to break your question prematurely.

Comment: Then we'll close this question as spam!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed the link, intending to just copy his question onto SO. But the question is long, rambling, and appears to include the entire page in a code listing. I'm neither qualified nor sufficiently ambitious to attack that mess.

So I voted to close. Not a real question. If he decides to put the effort in, he can always come back and ask it right.

Answer (score 4):

I just think it is plain rude to ask a question and then point people elsewhere. They are dedicating their time to helping out people and in turn dedicating their time to making StackOverflow a better site. To make them go to yet another site just to answer your question is a waste of their time.

If you want to ask a question, put in the effort to actually post it on StackOverflow. Format it, and provide only the relevant information so we can help you out with your problem, and then help all the other people with their problems.

In the end, Don't make it **hard** or **annoying** for us to help you.

Comment: agreed, but what should be done about it? just closed "not a real question" ?

Comment: Yes. Or Spam.

Comment: *Spam*: Unwanted Messages. Clearly, this is an unwanted question.

Answer (score 2):

That question, as far as I am concerned, is spam.

I mean, just look at it:

> I am posting [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic119348.htm) with my description and the code. I would need your suggestions.
>
> **It's about how to improve my recursive database driven navigation in ColdFusion.**

---

It is question asked, to only post a single link. That sounds a lot like spam to me.

Answer (score 0):

I look at this question as roughly the same thing as spam.  He posted his question on another site, and now he's asking us to go to that site and answer it.  If we allow that, then we have to allow people to link to Experts-Exchange, Java Ranch, and every other programming forum online.  If he wants the answer here, he's perfectly welcome to post the question here.  There's absolutely no reason for him to drive traffic to another site.

Comment: But what if *Experts-Exchange*  becomes a member of the League of Justice???

Comment: Then *me and my flying pig* are gonna go *ice-skating in hell!*